# No PHP-GD package available on Yum... But it is

Tags: centos, php, yum

### What I've done so far

- Installed CentOS 6.5 x64
- Installed cPanel
- Added REMI and EPEL repositories to the system
- Tried `yum --enablerepo=remi,epel install php-gd`

### The response:

> No package **php-gd** available.

#### Full response

```
root@hostname [~]# yum --enablerepo=remi install php-gd --verbose
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Config time: 0.042
Yum Version: 3.2.29
Setting up Package Sacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.crucial.com.au
 * epel: mirror.optus.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.crucial.com.au
 * remi: remi.kazukioishi.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.crucial.com.au
pkgsack time: 4.430
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Install Process
Checking for virtual provide or file-provide for php-gd
No package php-gd available.
Error: Nothing to do
root@hostname [~]#
```

### The actual package listing on [pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/) that says otherwise:

- http://pkgs.org/centos-6/remi-x86_64/php-gd-5.4.27-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm.html

### Question

Can anyone explain why an available package is not being picked up as available?

Comment: Try run `yum` with `--verbose` mode. Maybe there is a interesting lines there...

Comment: Just tried that, output has been added to my question

Comment: php-gd is also in updates repository; so no enablerepo should be necessary... can you try without it?

Comment: Could you add the output of `rpm -qa|grep php` to your question?

Comment: Added the output from a gist link. I think that cPanel might be interfering with the package installation... I'm searching online for solutions now.

Comment: Hi all, it is a cpanel thing. I have to rebuild PHP through it's GUI.

Comment: You'd be well served ditching cPanel. cPanel, Plesk, etc. are hefty, expensive, and highly limiting.

Comment: I agree. I hate it. But I am not the client =]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I am the service provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a Centos/Linux/Yum issue.

To enable PHP-GD on cPanel, you must go through cPanel's WHM interface and enable it via the following menu:

Home > Software > EasyApache (Apache Update)

and enable the GD module on the "Exhaustive Options List".
cPanel will then rebuild PHP and Apache with the updated module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this repo and it will work.

[CentOS]
name=CentOS
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6.5/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6.5/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

I don't think you have the package on your configured repos. If you see the package on pkgs.org it does not mean that your repo contains it. You have to check the url from your repositories. (the link from baseurl - in my example)

Comment: His real problem is that he's using cPanel, which overrides many of the system packages and does things its own way.